# How would you overlap divs?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

What would be the ideal way to get this thumbnail grid to overlap the two underlying divs (white and gray backgrounds)?  Im using Foundation 6 for this project but no success yet. I know i should probably be using z-index but its not working.  Any insight?

Link to design below:

[overlaping divs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThPvD.png)

Here is the code ive got so far:

```
<section class="instructors">
<div class="instructors-top">
  <h4>MEET OUR INSTRUCTORS</h4>
</div>
<div class="instructors-pic">
  <ul class="small-block-grid-3">
    <img src="images/kermit.png">
    <img src="images/patches.jpeg">
    <img src="images/chef.jpg">
    <img src="images/ButtersStotch.png">
  </ul>
  <ul class="small-block-grid-3">
    <img src="images/PeterGriffin.jpg">
    <img src="images/Eustace.jpg">
    <img src="images/homer.gif">
    <img src="images/buck.jpg">
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="instructors-bottom">
  <p>
    Each of our instrutors are the perfect combo of support and encouragement.<br>
    They are here to help you meet your goals and become a better mind here.
  </p>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.instructors-top {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;

}

.instructors-top h4 {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 55px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.instructors-bottom {
  background-color: #e4e5de;
  height: 300px;
  padding-top: 150px;
  z-index: 1;

}

.instructors-bottom p {
  color: gray;
  text-align: center;
}

.small-block-grid-3 img{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px;

}

.instructors-pic {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `position` property to move the bottom div down a bit. Then remove the height property and adjust padding for the bottom div.

Also note you had `z-index;` in the CSS for the `.instructors-bottom` div. `z-index` doesn't do *anything* unless you also include the `position` property for that selector. For example: the `z-index` in the `.instructors-top h4` selector isn't doing anything at all and could be removed.

```css
.instructors-top {
  height: 100px; /* ------------- adjusted for snippet */
 background-color: #fff;
}

.instructors-top h4 {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 55px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.instructors-bottom {
  background-color: #e4e5de;
  padding: 70px 0 40px 0; /* ------------- adjusted */
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;   /* ----------------- added */
  top: 200px; /* ------------------ added */
   /* ----------------------- removed height */

}

.instructors-bottom p {
  color: gray;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 30px; /* ------------- adjusted for snippet */
}

.small-block-grid-3 img{
  height: 100px; 
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px;

}

.instructors-pic {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}

   span { color: #f00; }
```

```html
<section class="instructors">
<div class="instructors-top">
  <h4>MEET OUR INSTRUCTORS</h4>
</div>
<div class="instructors-pic">
  <ul class="small-block-grid-3">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  </ul>
  <ul class="small-block-grid-3">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="instructors-bottom">
  <p>
    Each of our instructors <span>[FIXED TYPO]</span> are the perfect combo of support and encouragement.They are here to help you meet your goals and become a better mind here.
  </p>
</div>
</section>
```